# ¿Cómo soluciono: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)?

Tags: android

Estoy intentando crear un pdf dentro de un boton de un fragment de la siguiente manera:

```
      btnPdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
                } else {

                    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(400,600,1).create();
                    PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);
                    Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
                    canvas.drawText("ejemplo",40,50,paint);
                    pdfDocument.finishPage(page);
                        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/ejemplo");

                        try {
                            pdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));
                        }catch (IOException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        pdfDocument.close();

                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Los permisos en el manifest esta para el write and read external storage, como errror me sale
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/ejemplo: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
y no crea nada, ademas para añadir; en otro fragment guardo imagenes en el dispositivo con exito pero aun asi no se logra guardar el pdf

EL manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE " />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El problema:

> System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /storage/emulated/0/ejemplo: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

se debe a dos causas:

No tienes permiso, debes requerirlos manualmente y ademàs agregarlo en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

La ruta del archivo no existe, debes asegurar que la ruta del archivo que deseas acceder es correcta.

Puedes realizar lo siguiente verificar si existe el archivo de lo contrario crearlo, tu nombre de archivo no debe contener "/":

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"ejemplo");
if(!file.exists()){ // Si no existe, crea el archivo.
   file.createNewFile();
}
...
...
```

---

Si tu aplicaciòn tiene definido dentro del archivo `build.gradle` como minimo:

targetSdkVersion 29

El uso de `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` es obsoleto en API 29, para que pueda seguir funcionando define dentro del archivo AndroidManifest.xml `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`  :

```
<manifest ... >

  <application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Luego de implementar el metodo que mencionas, lo tuve que poner en try catch porque lo pedia, me sale el erro de java.io.IOException: Permission denied al hacerle un debug

`if (!file.exists()){
                            try {
                                file.createNewFile();

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }`

Comment: ah, claro si es necesario el manejo de exceptions, pero sabes acabo de ver un detalle tu archivo solo debe llamarse "ejemplo" , trata de nuevo: File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"ejemplo");

Comment: Aun asi no pasa nada, le he puesto mas metodos para poder habilitar los permisos, y los permisos para escribir están pero aun asi no se puede me sigue saliendo el mismo error :c , tambien otro detalle que vi es que con el Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() obtiene la direccion /storage/emulated/0 y pues con el device file explorer del mismo android se ve que no existe tal carpeta y dentro de esta dice de rojo permiso denegado

Comment: Puedes agregar el AndroidManifest donde declaras el permiso? Que sistema operativo usas?

Comment: Uso Windows en mi computadora, ya edite el manifest

Comment: me referia a tu dispositivo, pero el targetSDK es 29 en tu build.gradle?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116744/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-isaac-flores).

Comment: Excellent, it works for me in API 30: android: requestLegacyExternalStorage = "true"